# ckEditor5 online build works in development, not in production mode

Tags: next.js, build, production-environment, ckeditor5

Downloaded final build with required plugins from https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

Extracted build content into a folder name ckeditor5 in root of project.

Installed the local package with this command npm add file:./ckeditor5
Used these commands in nextjs to generate production build npm run build and npm run export

Getting the following error in production build of next js

```
849.02b0292964587ed3.js:1 TypeError: this.props.editor.create is not a function
    at ir._createEditor (849.02b0292964587ed3.js:1:27553)
    at Ge._creator (849.02b0292964587ed3.js:1:27214)
    at 849.02b0292964587ed3.js:1:19557
    at async ir._initializeEditor (849.02b0292964587ed3.js:1:27356)
    at async ir.componentDidMount (849.02b0292964587ed3.js:1:26738) 
Object
phase: "initialization"
willEditorRestart: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

console.log of editor module return the following

```
Module
__esModule: true
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

But it works perfectly in development mode

Comment: have you been able to find a solution on this?